# Is there an easy / quick method to load a parquet file from my Google Bucket into my Google Cloud Notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, parquet

I have just uploaded a parquet file into my bucket. I have fired up a new instance with a jupyter notebook. SO far I can read teh filenames from my bucket:

```
!pip install google-cloud-storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("mybucket")
filename = list(bucket.list_blobs())
for name in filename:
    print(name.name)

a = pd.read_parquet("gcs://mybucket/myfile.gzip")
```

When it gets to the last line, it just hangs... It's a 2GB file so it shouldn't take that long to load, It's been hanging for several hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting the file format of your file. From the [example doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')  
pd.read_parquet('df.parquet.gzip') 
 
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Notice the file name from the example which is **df.parquet.gzip**. I suggest you fix your file and follow the format as well.

Example:

**gs://mybucket/myfile.parquet.gzip**